# Typescript How to reduce generic parameters

Tags: typescript

Minimize the code here

```
function useTest<T extends object, U extends keyof T>(key: U) {
  let data: T[U][] = [] as T[U][];

  /** update */
  const update = (row: T[]) => {
    data = row.map((val) => val[key]);
  };

  return {
    update,
    data,
  };
}

const { data } = useTest<{ age: number; name: string }, "age">("age");
```

How to modify usetest and use it like this

```
const { data } = useTest<{ age: number; name: string }>("age");
```

Comment: `useTest` doesn't seem to make much sense without an argument of type `T`, but you can check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwCppVAPBxNADyjTABMVE4AjAKzWgD4AKAazQE8AuRDzuMEQYAlIgDeAKESIICHInIBDKEt4YA2v0HCAuht2IAvIgMBuSdMQAnNFBDWkUmTOWqANFYC+Fr5blgCuKKKkqIXsbI6Fg4uMFKAOZovGAgALY0aNZmiGBKacmIONYwYAnhrABEiWiVImZAA)

Comment: I updated the code, which minimizes the code

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this directly; partial type parameter inference (e.g., manually specify `T` but let the compiler infer `U`) is not supported.  There are workarounds like currying, shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkGALW), but nothing direct. See the linked question/answer for more information.